# Submit form is not working with in Bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am calling model on image click code for image click is
 `<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" href="file.php?id=<?php echo $path_id[$j] ;?>"> <?php echo "<img  src=\"member_images/".$path[$j]."\" height='200' width='200' class='margin'  />" ;?></a>`

I am passing the id of an image to model `file.php`. If I call `url/file.php?id=22` a code is working fine but when I call it as a model image is not submit.

Can anyone tell me where I was wrong?

In below code, I am getting id and view user image inside the model if user click edit icon image is changed using some javascript.On click submit button image should be updated if user change it otherwise `old_file_name` is stored in `$document` but this thing is not working inside model.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id =  $_GET['id'];
        $queryrun=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT file_name FROM member_images WHERE id='$id' ");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_object($queryrun);
        if($row->file_name!== $document)
        {
            unlink("member_images/".$row->file_name);
        }
        $query = " UPDATE member_images SET  file_name = '$document' where id = '$id' ";
        $queryrun = mysqli_query($db,$query);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your Data Updated Successfully";    
    }
    header("location:profiledemo.php");
}
?>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">

        <?php if(!empty($_GET['id'])){ ?>
        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="file" class="file1" name="image" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this);" style="display: none;" />
            <input type="hidden"  name="old_file_name" value="<?php if(isset($id)) echo $row->file_name;?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <img width="200px" height="200px" id="upfile" src="member_images/<?=$row->file_name;?>" style='position: relative;'>
            <img src="img/edit.png" class="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px; z-index: '10'" />
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <div class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve reply to me once you've read and implemented, will remove -1

Comment: please view edit